# Prove that $b_n$ is a Cauchy's sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence such that $b_1=1, b_{n+1} = b_n + (1+ 1/n)^{-n^2}$. Then prove that $~b_n~$ is a Cauchy's sequence

ok I wanna prove that it converges thus it meets Cauchy's criterion and not the opposite..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MAthJax formatting (See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Try this formatting in the next time. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that $$b_{n+1}=1+\sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac 1 k\right)^{-k^2}$$
and since
$$\begin{split}\left(1+\frac 1 k\right)^{-n^2}&=\exp\left(-k^2\ln\left(1+\frac 1 k\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-k^2\left(\frac 1 k+\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {k^2}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-k+\mathcal O\left(1\right)\right)\\
&=\mathcal O(e^{-k})
\end{split}$$
the series converges, and so does the $\{b_n\}$ sequence.

Comment: Thanks guys! But let me get this straight.. if I show that (1 * 1/n) ^-2n converges to the limit 1/e^n then the question is done ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the root test on the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n^2}$